# Content Cards HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me write an html/css code for creating a content card like this.

In this card the circular icon/ image will rotate on hover.

The main  issue I am facing is making the size of the image in the card larger than the actual size of the card. But it would be great if someone can help me write the code for the whole card.

Comment: Can you add what you already tried yourself so we have something to start form?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service please share your code what you have tried so far...

Comment: Could you write some of your code?